403 Forbidden when URL contains GET with encoded question mark / UnsafeAllow3F / rawurlencode
Since yesterday, when our Apache updated itself overnight, we started getting web responses saying 403 Forbidden. It looks like that encoding a "?" is not allowed anymore. The crazy thing is that PHP does exactly that when using rawurlencode(). We use it on user input in form fields that are transferred in GET requests. Do we need to change it in all these places? Using Google we read about an option named "UnsafeAllow3F", but I'm not sure how to set this.
Has this problem occurred for others? What are you doing to fix it?
In this code example, whenever $test contains a "?", the user gets a 403 Forbidden.
<a href='test?a=<?=rawurlencode($test);?>test</a>


This could be related to CVE-2024-38474. Please include in your question (by editing it, do not add it in a comment): 1. The version of Apache you're currently using and having this problem with. 2. Your complete .htaccess, if you have one.

Version is not enough. Build date is more important. I had apache 2.4.52 without issues. Upgrade changed it to apache 2.4.52 build date 2024-07-04 with this new issue. Fix is to add UnsafeAllow3F to the rewrite flags.

This only applies if you have a RewriteRule with ? in the substitution. See answer below.

We managed to fix this by adding the flag UnsafeAllow3F in our rewrite rules:
[PT]
was changed to
[PT,UnsafeAllow3F]
And this fixed the issue.  There is however a security vulnerability associated with this I can't seem to find much information on except for "The Apache Foundation recommends users upgrade to version 2.4.61."
I tried a manual compile and install of 2.4.61 on Ubuntu this morning, it was a bit of a nightmare and I couldn't get it working with Coldfusion in the end so am left waiting to see if they'll bring this fix to the Ubuntu package build (currently 2.4.52)

I figured out this fix myself today.
There's very little documentation on this. It appears that a very recent apache update has caused the issue and also introduced the UnsafeAllow3F flag.
It's not even tied to a new version of apache. I had this problem in production but could not reproduce in dev. Dev was running apache 2.4.52 built around 2024-06-something (sorry don't have the output anymore). Production (with issue) is running apache 2.4.52 built 2024-07-04.
So it appears to have been introduced around 2024-07-04.
Add UnsafeAllow3F to the flags and everything's working again.

@AndreasHuttenrauch It looks that the flag and the issue were introduced in version 2.4.60, released July 01, 2024: https://downloads.apache.org/httpd/CHANGES_2.4

This has been backported in the Ubuntu version, released as 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.10. See their changelog: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.52-1ubuntu4.12/changelog

I would strongly recommend upgrading to 2.4.60+ and not using UnsafeAllow3F or UnsafePrefixStat. This is related to 2 recently discovered vulnerabilities in Apache HTTP Server. There are few details available at the moment, but they have the potential to be fairly bad.
The Issue

https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2024-38474/ The fix for this involved forbidding encoded question marks in URLs by default and introduced the UnsafeAllow3F flag.
https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2024-38475/ Discovered at the same Master of PWN event in Toronto about a week ago, also by Orange Tsai. The fix introduced UnsafePrefixStat

Now, the first one, the one that you're running into, is not in and of itself too bad. It didn't get a CVE score at all. The second one got a score of 9.1/10. Given that they were discovered at the same time, by the same person, in the same area of the code, I would bet that they are closely related and that you will be much safer if you patch both.
Other people have mentioned that there are not many details. This is good: you have time to patch. Bad news: there is a deadline for patching. Per this tweet https://x.com/orange_8361/status/1807820224659706233, Orange Tsai will be describing the vulnerabilities in a lot more detail at Black Hat, and at that point, you will see a lot more exploitation of these issues.
How to address it
The issue here is not question marks in URLs as such. It is url-encoded question marks in URLs that are used for serving static files.
Bad version:

example.com/images?route=/cats/long-hair%3fsize=large
example.com/login?returnto=/cats/long-hair%3fsize=large

Good versions:

example.com/images/cats/long-hair?size=large
example.com/login?returnto=/cats/long-hair&returntoparams=size%3dlarge

Changing all instances of this may be a pain. Security is like that, I'm sorry. But these vulnerabilities are low-complexity, relatively high impact, and about to be documented publicly in a lot more detail. I would not want to be vulnerable if someone decides that these are good bugs for mass exploitation.

But such an URL structure is in all likelyhood very common across the web. There was really no other way to fix this vulnerability within Apache?

But it's blowing up on query parameters that are URLs - are you suggesting that the query parameters also should not be encoding ? to %3F - e.g. https://example.com?q=auth%2Flogin%3Furl%3Dpreferences is blowing up.

@fritzmg I don't know if there are better ways than changing your URL structure or remaining vulnerable - that would require fully reverse-engineering the patch or waiting until the blackhat presentation. And ya, most folks will just enable the Unsafe stuff but if you're adding a new feature or have only a few broken URLs, I wanted to make it clear that these flags are called unsafe for a reason

@user9645 as far as I know, having %3F anywhere will cause problems, yes. You could try to lock it down in other ways I supposed: e.g. only set the flag UnsafeAllow3F on one rewrite rule and then only allow a very small, hardcodesd list of parameters, so auth%2Flogin%3Furl%3Dpreferences specifically is allowed but most things are not. Having unsafe features enabled at all make me a touch nervous, but that would probably mitigate the risk pretty well

As it turns out (see my answer) - this only applies to RewriteRules with ? in their substitution.

This new setting breaks all websites (with a URL like domain?param=123), where the user clicks the login button and gets redirected to login?url=domain%F3param=123 (!) and on many other occasions where the URL is passed through. I fixed issues in my code all day (using base64 to encode all URLs) and I am still not done. So the first comment "There was really no other way to fix this vulnerability within Apache?" is absolutely serious.

Turns out you can indeed fix it using .htaccess by adding UnsafeAllow3F. An example: RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,UnsafeAllow3F]

To fix this, change your rewrite rules from this:
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]

to this:
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [UnsafeAllow3F]
RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags,UnsafeAllow3F]

References:
UnsafeAllow3F Apache documentation
USN-6885-1: Apache HTTP Server vulnerabilities (mod_rewrite)
I saw errors like "AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F" in the Apache error log on AlmaLinux starting 7/11/2024, and the above fixed it.

As stated in Apache's documentation this flag is only necessary if the rewrite target contains ?:

Setting this flag is required to allow a rewrite to continue If the HTTP request being written has an encoded question mark, '%3f', and the rewritten result has a '?' in the substitution. This protects from a malicious URL taking advantage of a capture and re-substitution of the encoded question mark.

An example would be
RewriteRule ^ index.php?x [L]

But if you have something equivalent to
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

to rewrite all requests to your PHP application (like in symfony/apache-pack's default .htaccess) you will not need the UnsafeAllow3F flag and URLs like /login?redirect=/lorem%3Ffoo=bar will continue to work as normal.
However, certain hosters (like Strato) did have a RewriteRule directive with a ? URL substitution in the general Apache configuration in their shared hosting setups. They have since rectified the issue (to some degree - URLs like /%3F are still disallowed).
Keep in mind that even if a RewriteRule containing a ? in their substitution would not apply - they are still evaluated by Apache in order and thus can cause the 403 response.

FYI a very common way to set up a CodeIgniter site uses RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] so that the user-visible URL does not have index.php in it.

@user9645 that is not the official recommendation though. See https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file

It is not clear to me why this is so, but apparently the recommended config does not work in some cases, and adding the ? fixes it. See this SO entry and the comment therein by @Mitya. We had it set that way since 2013, but I just tried removing the ? and it seems to still work. Not sure now why we were using the ?.

We had a similar problem to you. We are also passing return url to the next page, and are getting 403 blocked because of the ? sign. I found a solution by replaing all instances of ? with the html entity of that sign (&#63;), before urlencoding.
<a href='test?a=<?=rawurlencode(str_replace('?','&#63;',$test));?>test</a>

It magically fixed the problem for us, and the best part is that when the apache server receives the string, it decodes the html entity(&#63;) back to the ? sign.

I just ran into this with a site running Craft CMS. Craft uses an .htaccess rewrite that includes a querystring.
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

Looks like they will be removing it in a future release. For existing sites you can update the RewriteRule in web/.htaccess to this. (Remove the query string and QSA).
RewriteRule (.+) index.php [L]

Details in this Github issue https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/15825

UnsafeAllow3F is a remake of 1997's Magic Quotes. I don't know who was so dump to have this idea again. I wrote a blog article to make place for my rant:
https://launix.de/launix/broken-websites-after-apache-update-unsafeallow3f-a-game-you-cannot-win/

That blog post is wrong. Apache will not throw a 403 Forbidden for every URL that contains %3F. Only rewritten paths (with mod_rewrite) are affected. Nothing to do with magic quotes either, which was php-specific.

You didn't read the article well. Did you understand the faulty concept of magic quotes and do you see how apache is repeating this mistake again?

Apache is not trying to escape anything (like magic quotes was). Apache now refuses a request if it contains an encoded ? under certain configurations (mod_rewrite) if some conditions are met (if ? is part of the pattern substitution), unless the new introduced UnsafeAllow3F is set. We don't know the details (this was a fix to a recent security issue), and certainly the situation is not ideal (as you mention, UnsafeAllow3F is invalid syntax in earlier versions)
